# overloaded method value corr with alternatives

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying compute the correlation between 2 features, that are being read from two separate text files as shown below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.Statistics
import scala.io.Source

object Corr {
     def main() {
            val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
                .master("local")
                .appName("Correlation")
                .getOrCreate()

            val sc = sparkSession.sparkContext


            val feature_1 = Source.fromFile("feature_1.txt").getLines.toArray
            val feature_2 = Source.fromFile("feature_2.txt").getLines.toArray

            val feature_1_dist = sc.parallelize(feature_1)
            val feature_2_dist = sc.parallelize(feature_2)


            val correlation: Double = Statistics.corr(feature_1_dist, feature_2_dist, "pearson")
            println(s"Correlation is: $correlation")
      }
} 

Corr.main()
```

However, I get the following error:

```
overloaded method value corr with alternatives:
  (x: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[java.lang.Double],y: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[java.lang.Double],method: String)scala.Double <and>
  (x: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.Double],y: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.Double],method: String)scala.Double
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String], org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String], String)
        val correlation: Double = Statistics.corr(feature_1_dist, feature_2_dist, "pearson")
```

What I am trying to do, looks very similar to the example [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-statistics.html) but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What is `Statistics` ? Can you add your imports? The above posted code has no `import` statements.

Comment: @Paul Sorry about that. I have just added them.

Comment: Reading the features into arrays stored on the master is already a suspicious move, that should not occur if the features are large.

Comment: The parallelized method of reading a data file is `val lines = sc.readText('filename.txt')` which is often followed by a rdd map operation that parses the lines into data structures but instead you are reading the data files with `scala.io.Source` and then parallelizing the obtained arrays.

Comment: That is not the cause of the error, though, just a stylistic note.  If the input file is large enough to overflow memory on a single machine, then `sc.readText` is necessary because it spreads the lines across machines.

Comment: @Paul I get the following error though: `value readText is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkContext`

Comment: I am sorry, it is `sc.textFile()` see here under "external datasets": http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is stated in error message, you need to have a `RDD[Double]`, but you have `RDD[String]`. So, you could do something like this (if you have one number per row):

```
val feature_1 = Source.fromFile("feature_1.txt").getLines.toArray.map(_.toDouble)
val feature_2 = Source.fromFile("feature_2.txt").getLines.toArray.map(_.toDouble)
```